# How to check if a value exists in a bit-enum?

Tags: c++, enums, bit-manipulation

I have an `enum`:

```
enum Rule
{
    BIT_NONE,
    BIT_ONE,
    BIT_TWO = 1 << 1,
    BIT_THREE = 1 << 2,
    BIT_FOUR = 1 << 3
};
```

Now, how do I verify that a specific `int` value belongs to the above `enum`? Note that the idea is to also allow any combination of `BIT_TWO`, `BIT_THREE`, and `BIT_FOUR`, ergo the valid values are `{0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}`.

If I check `BIT_NONE <= val && val <= BIT_FOUR`, it won't permit the combinations as mentioned above, but will also include the unwanted `{3, 5, 7}`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You generally check bits by carefully create *masks* using bitwise OR, and then check the value by bitwise AND.

Comment: But in this case there will be 4 masks, do I need to type them all, or is there another way. The `enum` will grow in the future, and it'll be a pain to maintain that mask list everytime!

Comment: Have you considered using `std::bitset`?

Comment: @diametralpitch Legacy code; change not feasible

Comment: Yes it might take multiple masks and multiple bitwise ands, but with legacy code you have to work within the confined walls created by it. Either that or do a major refactoring. To make make it a *little* easier break out the conditions into functions, so you have a single function checking for e.g. the values you mentioned. At least that way it will be easier to modify in a single place if more bits are added or the masks need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs some bit operation tricks:

To allow all `enum` as a single bit, you need to be sure it's less than `BIT_FOUR`, and it's only a single bit. The latter can be detected by `!((val-1)&val)`:

```
bool is_allowed_single(unsigned val) {
    return BIT_NONE <= val && val <= BIT_FOUR && !((val-1)&val);
}
```

Then combination of certain bits is also valid:

```
bool is_allowed_combination(unsigned val) {
    return !(val & ~(BIT_TWO|BIT_THREE|BIT_FOUR));
}
```

Finally, we get:

```
bool is_allowed(unsigned val) {
    return is_allowed_single(val) || is_allowed_combination(val);
}
```

Comment: What happens in `is_allowed_single()` when `val` is `0`?

Comment: @CinCout `true`.

Comment: That's because `val - 1` will be wrapped around to `UNSIGNED_MAX`?

Comment: @CinCout yes. `unsigned` arithmetics is always defined.

Comment: Oh yeah. UB is for `signed`. I always get confused among the two.

Answer (score 0):

Since the enum is small, there is an other way: using a pre-defined mask of all the valid values.
That mask is the OR of `1 << {0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}`, so `0x5557`.

Then check if the bit corresponding to the value is set:

```
bool is_allowed(unsigned val) {
    return (0x5557 & (1 << val)) != 0;
}
```

This has a pre-condition that values are not wildly outside of the set, but they could easily be checked for with a comparison if they are expected to exist.